# ASP.NET Web Api - Authorise from querystring values and API security

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

In designing and learning about an ASP.NET Web API I've come across a few challenges I'd like some help and discussion on.

Inspired by this [excellent post](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) on designing a Secure REST API without OAuth I'm wondering how best to approach validating the various tokens and information I intend to ask for.

Brief summary is I'll be asking for (in the querystring) the following info..

- user id
- api key
- timestamp
- a signature hash based on a secret key the user has been issued and hashed together with the request values

My question / wondering is this :

If this is a sound approach, what would be the best way to implement this using ASP.NET Web API?

I'm currently thinking about either using a custom attribute that I can mark my methods with, kind of an Authorize attribute that grabs the required from the query string or some POCO type object that contains all the values and I can use to keep all the authorisation type code in one place.

Has anyone got any experience or thoughts on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could probably invoke your auth code in either the global Begin_Request handler or the global Authenticate_Request handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, as you might have seen, the `AuthorizeAttribute` approach is used in Web API. I think that this is a fairly good approach in that we can put this attribute on individual items that need authorization.

I have done authorization by extending the `System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. After you extend it, all authorization details are up to you and you have plenty approaches to choose from.

Comment: Sure. My BasicAuthorizationFilterAttribute extends the System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute and then overrides the OnAuthorization method. Since the OnAuthorization method accepts HttpActionContext as its parameter. This object allows me to access the request message and take the required data from there (HttpRequestHeaders.Authorization header in this case). From there, onwards the value has to be checked. If it is valid, the method returns. Otherwise the method assigns the actionContext.Response object and "unsuccessful authorization" response is returned.